# React-Native + Android, only build for armeabi architecture

Tags: android, android-ndk, react-native

NOTE: I'm being provided those libraries, I can't make other ones for other architectures.

I'm currently porting an Android app to react-native that uses native libraries, but I only have the **armeabi** ones available. No problem so far with the original project, since [armeabi is supported by all the x86/x86_64/armeabi-v7a/arm64-v8a devices](http://ph0b.com/android-abis-and-so-files/).

Then when I generate a new project from react-native and include those armeabi files, while running the apk some libraries are not found. When I unzip the apk generated by the original project I can find the folder: lib/armeabi with all the libraries, so no problem. Now when I unzip my apk generated by react-native I have 2 folders: lib/armeabi-v7a and lib/x86 and some libraries are missing.

Here is my gradle configuration with react-native:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.poc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }

        veryVerbose {

        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable true
                jniDebuggable false
                signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            }
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    // Player library
    veryVerboseCompile fileTree(dir: 'veryVerboseLibs', include: ['*.jar'])
    debugCompile fileTree(dir: 'releaseLibs', include: ['*.jar'])
    releaseCompile fileTree(dir: 'releaseLibs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Google
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"

    // Square
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'

    // From node_modules
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

Seems like react-native auto-generate some configuration regarding architectures, a bit new to me, I would need to tell gradle to build for armeabi and include all those libraries into a lib/armeabi folder in my final apk.

And basically what I get from logcat and running the apk is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.siminntvpoc-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.siminntvpoc-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.siminntvpoc-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libViewRightWebClient.so"
```

Comment: So your app is building fine?
This error you must have gotten only in emulator not in actual device. Is that the case ?

Comment: Also take into account that react native [doesn't support 3rd party 64bit libraries and cannot mix+match 32 and 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628767/8295283) libraries (as of August 2017)

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify what kind of architecture you want in `application.mk`.

To support all architecture use this attribute `APP_ABI := all` in `application.mk`  file

here is document https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html

Answer (score 2):

if you use the Experimental Gradle Build

add this to build.gradle

```
abiFilters.addAll([
            "armeabi-v7a",
            "arm64-v8a",
            "x86",
            "x86_64"
    ])
```

else

```
APP_ABI:=all in Application.mk
```

[More](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/building-native-android-libraries-with-the-latest-experimental-android-plugin.html)

Comment: Tried it but in vain.