# Android ReactNative java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:could find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have been trying to add ReactNative to my existing android application. I followed the instructions from [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#content) link. I could add it but the app gets crashed once I open the react native activity. I have started server using

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

and started react-native using

```
react-native start
```

I get a dialogue that the js files are loading. But finally end up with a crash. Following is the error that is being printed in logcat:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:213)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:178)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutor.<clinit>(JSCJavaScriptExecutor.java:19)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer(ReactInstanceManager.java:413)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:236)
```

I am completely lost as I am unable to figure out the cause for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you **do** have the .so file in your project? it's (in theory) linked correctly?

Comment: No. I didn't add any of it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Since @Anu there have been some changes in the stacktrace, but the error is the same. Deeper on the stacktrace I find it comes from: `at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)` which is very strange, because line 44 is the end of the file, not `onCreate` method. Using RN 0.46.4

Comment: It's interesting to see so many people having this problem in their local. I could only get this in Production, through Crashlytics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is caused by the following issue (open for 2 years) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814

From the issue:

> React Native on Android doesn't provide a 64-bit version of the `libreactnativejni.so` native library, which can cause compatibility issues on 64-bit devices. I ran into this while attempting to integrate React Native with a large existing application I'm developing.

Reaction from Facebook:

> "*Thanks for reporting! Yes we don't provide 64-bit version of the native code and the system should always fall back to 32-bit.*"
>
> And:
>
> "*Most Android projects use a number of 3rd-party libraries, and any that include native 64-bit code will cause React Native to fail.*"

The following SO answer [Use 32-bit jni libraries on 64-bit android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27202958/8295283) explains fallback to 32-bit libraries and the fact you cannot mix. So if 64-bit is found, all should be 64-bit

I suggest reading along the Github issue #2814. There are multiple fixes proposed, but it depends on your situation what works.

The issuer has also written a blog about it: [Mixing 32- and 64-bit Dependencies in Android](https://corbt.com/posts/2015/09/18/mixing-32-and-64bit-dependencies-in-android.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: PS @Anu I saw you also posted on the github issue. Sorry, I think this is the current status, but there is some (slow) work on it. But eventually RN will have to support 64bit, sometime soon I think.

Comment: Is it supposed to work properly now with react-native 60.5? I still get the same error with 60.5 even though react native added support for 64 bit in 59.1.

Comment: How is this a solution?

Answer (score 38):

actually in my case these steps worked:

1. uninstall the app from the device
2. close `Metro Bundler`
3. run `./gradlew clean` on android directory
4. run `react-native run-android`

hope to help you.

Answer (score 22):

This has fixed my issue :

```
   ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
```

This should be placed `build.gradle` defaultConfig section.

Comment: Tnx man! you saved me!! but also a question. does adding this code has any side-effects? i mean if solution was this easy why React-Native team didn't put this in their code?

Comment: @Amas I don't know is was your case but I got this problem because someone deletes this section in the code. :)

Comment: It was removed by React team; `react-native upgrade` command overwrite old version with one without ndk.

Comment: Can confirm that this no longer works as of react-native `0.65`

Answer (score 5):

To me what worked was to clean project build and build it again. [image]

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1:

follow these steps:

1. uninstall the app from the device
2. close `Metro Bundler`
3. run `./gradlew clean` on android directory
4. run `react-native run-android`

hope to help you.

## Solution 2:

you can use the old version of soloader by adding **configurations.all** into your **build.gradle**

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2"
    }
}
```

like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61695629/8079868

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue, update fresco library that is support for app bundle is 2.0.0 below this will not support,

Update: For me the issue got solved after updating fresco to 2.0.0, because 1.11.0 apparently didn't have support for Android App Bundles. I don't know if you all had the same problem, though.

just do this :

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when running on Android 30. Following addition to the `android/build.gradle` file worked for me:

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
           // use 0.9.0 to fix crash on Android 11
            force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0"
  }
}
```

[Credits](https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader/issues/59#issuecomment-669161376)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be lib\x86_64\libreactnativejni.so not found due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'
Try the following steps.

1. Uninstall the apk
2. Clean the android folder

   - Navigate to android folder `cd android`.
   - Clean the directory using 
     gradle
   - For Windows, `gradlew clean`
   - For Linux, `./graldew clean`
3. Now you can try `react-native run-android --no-jetifier`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Goto Android Studio -> Build -> clean project.
Step 2: delete the project in your device.
Step 3: run react-native start.
Step 4: run npx react-native run-android.

- It's working for me, no need of any gradle related changes.

Answer (score -3):

if you are fresco libray then make sure use latest version and set the properties as false :

```
shrinkResources false
minifyEnabled false
```

Inside `build.gradle` file.