# React Native app starts to a white screen

Tags: android, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-native

I'm using React Native to develop an Android app. Sometimes, after I run `react-native run-android` and my app starts, it hangs on a white screen. Shaking my phone doesn't do anything, and when I click 'pause' in the VSCode debugger it has no effect. If I press the Home button to background the app, then click on the app again, it launches normally and debugging works as expected. Is this a known issue? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: For a really good fix to this problem going forward see my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65958958/5354268

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your `android` folder in Android studio
2. Press the green `Play` button
3. Open the `logcat` window from the bottom bar
4. Make sure the `Device` and `Process` are point to the right value, then inspect any error there

I don't have this problem, you need to inspect what happened at run-time to see how to fix this.

Comment: I had the same issue, checked the logcat and found I had some errors to deal with.

Comment: Useful tip... I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368926/android-reactnative-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerrorcould-find-dso-to-load-libre/45628767) error, and the solution `./gradlew clean` in android folder fixed the blank white screen

Answer (score 0):

have you resolve this issue?
if you use react-native-vector-icons, make sure you update those fonts(Octicons.ttf and etc) in assets/fonts.
it works fine on iOS but on android, whenever the app is installed then sometimes it gets blank white screen after splash, but it works fine sometimes as well. it is just randomly happened
once i updated them, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer for people hitting this question possibly facing the same issue as me - blank white screen on android, ios working fine:

Make sure in your `MainActivity.java` you have `getMainComponentName()` function:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "devApp3";
    }
}
```