# React Native white blank screen issue

Tags: react-native

Always getting white blank screen when running the app on the physical device in android case. Using `react-native-navigation` can't able to detect the bug please help!

I have created a fresh `react-native` project and integrated the `react-native-navigation` library into it and when I am running the app in my physical device by running the command `yarn run android` it runs but shows blank white screen in android. Once it runs successfully but now it won't.

Comment: Please provide more details / code to help the community understand your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "react-native init" command for the creating the project as it only build react-native not expo and the other node modules for you and then build for the particular platforms for eg. in my case "react-native run-android" and it works.

Comment: how to do it in a project cloned from git?

Comment: umm... is the repo empty or it contains something ?

Answer (score 28):

run react-native start in a separate terminal and then run react-native run-android.

Comment: At first run of react-native run-android I got blank screen. On second run it worked. Weird.

Answer (score 12):

i recently faced two kind of white screen problem

1.always showing white screen (due to bundling..)
solutions is

```
react-native start
```

and then

```
react-native run-android
```

2.it shows white screen some particular seconds or suddenly always shows white screen in   properly working app

due to app  cache or traffic

solutions is

Androidmanifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 8):

Running **./gradlew clean** on android folder and then uninstalling the app from the phone worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If `Debug JS Remotely` is on then also we see the blank screen. I have recently come across this issue. So check if you are already running `Debug JS Remotely`. If you are running it already then just stop remote debugging. And it will work.

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case I had a browser tab open with the debug console and that was causing the issue. I was able to run the app like normal.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, was using my Phone to test and develop, and suddenly white screen issue appeared.

The app was not loading at all, no error, no code update only white screen comes up after npx react-native run-android.

My solution was to clear the phone cache as it was loading from cache.

I restarted my phone then cleared all cache and then it worked for me.

Comment: Diwakar, when you mention clear phone cache it's better to tell the steps on how you clear. Do you clear app cache from setting? Do you reload the app? Do you run `react-native start --reset-cache`? Do you run `./gradlew clean` inside Android folder?  Try to be more specific when answering. It will help OP to better understand.

Comment: This worked for me, by clearning app cache in the phone

Answer (score 2):

There is step-by-step what I do to run app on physical android device:

1. Open 'android' folder from app folder in IntelliJ
2. Run in IntelliJ, target: USB device
3. After .apk finish installing, shift-right click in app folder, run PowerShell, type 'react-native run-android'
4. After it finish, open app on physical device, shake it to open developer menu, and hit 'Reload'

you can also hold menu button on your device to open developer menu(while app is running)

Comment: This is what I got when i followed the above steps "Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project." :(

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue in the emulator. So the way I solved it is by going into Android settings - Apps - select the app, and force stop it. Then I tried opening the app again and it worked.
Before I did this, I removed the 'build' folder under /android/app/ and re-ran. Did not work.

Comment: Also faced this issue. Worked after doing "Force stop" and open it

Answer (score 1):

I have recently faced this kind of white screen problem

1.always showing white screen after Release

"npx react-native start"
and then

"npx react-native run-android"

2.it shows white screen some particular seconds or suddenly always shows the white screen in a properly working app

due to app cache or traffic and android Newer version also in some case when you are using  API with HTTP instead of HTTPS

The reason is  that newer android versions are more secure and they try to restrict HTTP request

solutions are
add this line in path `project\android\app\src\main\androidmanifest.xml`:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that often resolves this problem for me is re-installing your node_modules folder and cleaning your gradle build. You can do this manually, however, if you've run into this problem once or many times, consider running a shell script to automate this process.

Create a file called `clean.sh` and paste this inside:

```
echo "Removing node modules from $1 then reinstalling..."
cd $1
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
echo "Cleaning gradle project..."
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
```

**If using npm, change "yarn" above to "npm".**

Put the file above in the parent directory of your project (if your project is located at `C:\Users\your.name\projects\project1` put the `clean.sh` file at `C:\Users\your.name\projects\`).

To run the script, inside of Git Bash or your Unix terminal run this (make sure to change the name of the directory below to the parent directory of your project):

```
cd C:/Users/your.name/projects
./clean.sh <project-name>
```

Now when restarting your app, try also reset the packager's cache.

With yarn:

```
yarn start --reset-cache
yarn android
```

With npm:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a metro terminal running from my previous project. closing it and running the new project again solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen). I try many ways to fix this issue but it's not working and i think this is the best way.

Comment: Thanks, for the solution Hoàng Vũ Anh i solved it by my way :) will try your too....

Answer (score 0):

For me my wifi was disconnected on my test device.

I had to make sure both my computer running the react packager/server and my device were connected to the same wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

It can not find its navigation's route. You should check the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1: I tried npx react-native start to run metro.

2: Then write npx react-native run-android in cmd, there was still a white blank screen.

3: I still faced the same issues, then I always comment on every single component, and automatically, I resolve the error. This is the best technique I ever used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get it working on a Android device, make sure you have first tried to clear cache for the App, doesn't matter if reinstalled.
Try the other answers only after you have cleared cache.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a white screen on react native indicates a memory issue.
Check the device's memory before install.
If you are using an emulator you can increase the memory through the device configuration on Android Studio.
Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the container in a View, make sure the View stretches to fill the container using flex:1:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
 return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <NavigationContainer>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  </View>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was going into android studio and selecting the simulator from the simulator manager and using 'cold start'.