# react native application on emulator stuck on white screen

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, android-emulator

on android only and only in the emulator, if I run my react native app, the app does not launch and get stuck on a white screen. The bundler in the terminal does not receive any connections requests.

It used to work and it works when I run on a device using the same command  (react-native run-android)

I'm on react native 0.57.8

[image]

[image]

Here are the logs I get from react-native log-android:

```
    02-26 17:12:21.527  6544  6544 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
    02-26 17:12:21.606  6544  6544 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
    02-26 17:12:21.606  6544  6544 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
    02-26 17:12:21.629  6544  6544 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
    02-26 17:12:21.629  6544  6544 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
    02-26 17:12:21.629  6544  6544 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
    02-26 17:12:21.665  6544  6604 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
    02-26 17:12:21.727  6544  6604 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
    02-26 17:12:21.729  6544  6604 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
    02-26 17:12:21.735  6544  6604 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
    02-26 17:12:21.735  6544  6604 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
```

I even tried reverting to older code version via git to version that I know worked, but that still fails, so I think there might be a configuration issue with my machine and the emulator, but I'm unsure what.

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: maybe try clearing the bundler cache, e.g  `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  wait until it's running and then start the emulator.

Comment: The only possibility coming to my mind is the network connectivity make sure your emulator has active network connection, i can see your wifi has a small cross what is the reason for that ? also check if your emulator has any proxy settings or something ?

Comment: whats the OS version of the emulator?

Comment: Thanks @Navneetkumar. your comment put me on the right track. I had tried to setup Charles Proxy in the past and the setting were still active...

Comment: Great happy to hear that your problem is fixed, it would be even better if my answer was accepted .. :D

Comment: @Navneetkumar I can't accept a comment as an answer. I you add an answer below, I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: I wrote an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65958958/5354268

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility coming to my mind is the network connectivity :

1. make sure your emulator has active network connection.
2. I can see your wifi has a small cross what is the reason for that ?
3. Also, check if your emulator has any proxy settings or something ?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Amir's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59800538/2761641) answer I deleted my Android Virtual Device and installed a newer one, still I was getting blank screen.

I read that some people made it work by clearing phone cache. Finally I tried, it cleared phone cache and cleared phone data related with App. This is little intriguing as I had already installed a new virtual device, so there should not be case of cache,

> > In short **by clearing app cache in emulator I was able to get back to working App**

Comment: This worked for me. I was facing the same issue, had internet connectivity on my emulator, everything else seemed fine. I then cleared the cache and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Navneet Kumar, I found out that a few weeks ago I had tried to set up Charles Proxy on the emulator. I thought that setting was limited to that one emulated device, but apparently that setting is shared across all devices. 
Reverting those setting and everything is working (https://medium.com/@daptronic/the-android-emulator-and-charles-proxy-a-love-story-595c23484e02).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, You can trace [this issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2687) for more information. The only solution they mentioned there to fix this problem is to create another emulator device in avd.

---

### Update

Another solution was to run the application by the android studio (by opening android folder in android studio) and run it to see errors!

Answer (score 0):

I just closed the app uninstalled it from emulator and then ran `react-native run-android` it's just fine now

Answer (score 0):

1. Just Go to command Prompt type Ipconfig.
2. Open Extended Controls for Android Emulator->Settings-Proxy
3. Check and Paste the Ip Address in Emulator Proxy Settings and put the port number as e.g 8888
4. Restart the Application.
   [Check Image For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDgzx.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I started a new project and transferred components into it from an old one, I could see my app was operating through console.log but was left with a blank screen.

Eventually I figured out **style={{flex: 1}}** required on root component D'OH

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-maps` were causing that issue
when I uninstalled this package `react-native-maps`, app runs normally

Properly working app image after removing package

[image]

Comment: Emoji spamming is extremely distracting. Please leave that out of answers in the future.

Comment: @Iva Next time you see a user submit two of the same answer, please flag one as a self-duplicate of the other.