# How to remove the blank white screen in android phone in react native project?

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react-native.

I am making a project in react-native with my android phone connected to my laptop at the USB port. When I run the project I see a blank screen on my phone. My phone is android version 9.

First I ran `npm start` and then I ran `npm run android`.

I ran adb -s device-name reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081. Still the screen on my phone is blank.

This is my App.tsx file:

```
import "./i18n"
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { YellowBox } from "react-native"
import { NavigationContainerRef } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { contains } from "ramda"
import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens"
import { SafeAreaProvider, initialWindowSafeAreaInsets } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

import { RootNavigator, exitRoutes, setRootNavigation } from "./navigation" 
import { useBackButtonHandler } from "./navigation/use-back-button-handler"
import { RootStore, RootStoreProvider, setupRootStore } from "./models/root-store"
import * as storage from "./utils/storage"
import getActiveRouteName from "./navigation/get-active-routename"
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements';
import * as theme from 'theme';

enableScreens()

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
"componentWillMount is deprecated",
"componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated",
"Require cycle:",
])

const canExit = (routeName: string) => contains(routeName, exitRoutes)

export const NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY = "NAVIGATION_STATE"

const App: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
const navigationRef = useRef<NavigationContainerRef>()
const [rootStore, setRootStore] = useState<RootStore | undefined>(undefined)
const [initialNavigationState, setInitialNavigationState] = useState()
const [isRestoringNavigationState, setIsRestoringNavigationState] = useState(true)

setRootNavigation(navigationRef)
useBackButtonHandler(navigationRef, canExit)

    const routeNameRef = useRef()
    const onNavigationStateChange = state => {
    const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current
    const currentRouteName = getActiveRouteName(state)

    if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
        // track screens.
        __DEV__ && console.tron.log(currentRouteName)
    }

    // Save the current route name for later comparision
    routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName

    // Clear the storage if we are navigating to auth stack
    if ( ['register', 'login', 'forgotpassword'].includes(currentRouteName) ) {
        storage.remove(NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY);
    } else {
        // Persist navigation state to storage
        storage.save(NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY, state)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        setupRootStore().then(setRootStore)
    })()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    const restoreState = async () => {
        try {
            const state = await storage.load(NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY)

            if (state) {
                setInitialNavigationState(state)
            }
        } finally {
            setIsRestoringNavigationState(false)
        }
    }

    if (isRestoringNavigationState) {
        restoreState()
    }
}, [isRestoringNavigationState])

if (!rootStore) {
    return null
}

return (
    <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
        <SafeAreaProvider initialSafeAreaInsets={initialWindowSafeAreaInsets}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <RootNavigator
                    ref={navigationRef}
                    initialState={initialNavigationState}
                    onStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
                />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    </RootStoreProvider>
)
}

export default App
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native white blank screen issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705627/react-native-white-blank-screen-issue)

Comment: No that does not.