# React Native App is displaying a blank white screen when connected with a device

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native to build an android app, but i am having an issue. The issue is whenever i connect the app to my android device (via USB) or emulator, the app display a white blank screen. But if i open the app offline (if not connected to the react native development server), the app display the contents in the app ('app.js' code). I'm beginner in react native app development (this is my first time). I don't know why the app is behaving like that. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You seem to have solved this problem, but I have a really good fix for this if you run into this in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65958958/5354268

Answer (score 3):

If the white screen comes up after the app is built, close the app from the phone. Then open it again.

Make sure it says "Running" in "Metro".

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this issue by running `react-native start` in one terminal and then `react-native run-android` in different terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the previous APK. Restart your metro bundler and run again