# I started my react-native app BUT its not showing up on the emulator :)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

I started my brand new react native app after installing the dependencies.

I started metro up as well, gradle bundled everything and converting the javascript.

However my emulator screen is not showing anything on the screen. EVEN when I update something in the App.js file?

[image]

is this because of the App.js having red errors?

[image]

Comment: Can you check the terminal? What is it showing?

Comment: here is a link to the image of the terminal -> https://i.ibb.co/P1DK9yy/Screenshot-2021-11-10-202905.png

Comment: If you press `R` in the terminal, does it refresh the page in the emulator?

Comment: Yes it does, it also shows that it is redownloading everything at the top of the emulator, but once it gets to 100% it goes away, and the screen remains blank. Thank you for replying by the way!

Comment: Close the app from the emulator, and see again. If not, then also remove everything from `App.js` and try rendering a plain `Hello World`

Comment: Tried both, Still nothing :/

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705627/react-native-white-blank-screen-issue

Comment: will do, ill give it my all. Thank you for your time :). If you discover anything else feel free to drop a comment kind stranger. Cheers!

Comment: This answered my question! Everything is up and running, Thank you :)!